# AngularJS nav active class won't show

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm Quite new to AngularJS and I try to develop a nav bar, which changes the activeclass. So I tried to make a function in my controller to define the active class.

My html code of the nav:
[image: nav code]

The controller:

[image: Controller class]

I compiled with grunt and there are no errors/warnings. Every navigation item hasn't the active class. How does this come?

Comment: You have a syntax error in your last li tag. Removed unnecessary '"><a ng-href=">' from row for '/contact'.

Comment: Relatively new to angular as well so I'll post it as a comment instead of an answer, but have you tried `ng-class="HeaderCtrl.getClass('/')"`  or does the `$scope` in your js file take care of that?

Comment: @Jared I think that by defining the ng-controller="HeaderCtrl" the function knows it needs to refer to the HeaderCtrl

Comment: @Fakerun thanks for the mistake, I changed it but still doesn't work.

Comment: To all the answers saying you can't use this syntax for `ng-class`, [you're wrong](http://jsbin.com/zopiwuwahi/1/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not injecting `$location` in your controller here:

```
['$scope', function($scope, $location) ...]
```

Add it to the injection list:

```
['$scope', '$location', function($scope, $location) ...]
```

Your syntax for `ng-class` is fine.

Comment: This is a working solution. 1 little issue, Home is always active, can you give an explanation for it?

Comment: Because `$location.path().substr(0, path.length)` is always going to be `/` when `path.length` is 1 (the first character in all of your paths is a `/`)

Answer (score -2):

[Ng-class directive has a bit different syntax](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass). It should me a map of class names and condition when it's applied. In your case it could be like this:

```
<li ng-class="{active: getClass(PATH)}">...</li>
```

While actually much more mature solution for your case, could be the `ui-sref-active` of the of [angular ui router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router). It takes more time for initial configuration, but using it you can not only menu highlighting but the whole state management within you angular app. See example here : http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref-active